# Not able to handle duplicate Tweet in android

Tags: android, twitter

Am working with sharing text and image in twitter with android using `action_send` Intent. I get a success response code in `onActivityResult` for both **success** and **dulipcate** tweet. Can any one suggest me on how to handle this problem.

**My Code**

```
Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"This is a Test.");
tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,pictureUri);
tweetIntent.setType("image/jpeg");

PackageManager packManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> resolvedInfoList = packManager.queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
boolean resolved = false;
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolvedInfoList) {
if (resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.startsWith("com.twitter.android")) {
tweetIntent.setClassName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
resolved = true;
break;}}

if (resolved) {
startActivityForResult(tweetIntent, 2);
} else {
Toast.makeText(Store_Detail_Activity.this,"Twitter app isn't found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
if(resultCode==0)
Toast.makeText(Store_Detail_Activity.this,"Tweet cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else if(resultCode==-1) // Success Result Code
Toast.makeText(Store_Detail_Activity.this,"Tweeted successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your code I come to know that you are opening Twitter app to do tweet. So, I don't know for that way, but if you are ready to use Tweeter4J api for do tweet then you can surely get to know what is successfully tweet and which one is duplicate.

Please check my below code to know for tweet.

```
public void updateStatus(final StatusUpdate status) throws Exception {
    mProgressDlg.setMessage("Posting...");
    mProgressDlg.show();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            try {
                mTwitter.updateStatus(status);
                i = 0;
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Not Posted: In Catch");

                message = e.getErrorMessage();
                System.out.println("MESSAGE:::: "+message);
                //asdasd
                //Toast.makeText(context, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //e.getMessage();
                i= 1;
            }

            mPostHandler.sendEmptyMessage(i);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Again let me inform you that it is only useful if you are using [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) library to do tweet on Twitter.